# Include JSTL dependency with Maven

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, maven

I am using maven2, how do I add a dependency to JSTL (The JSP Standard Tag Library) ?

Comment: There is a subtlety between version 1.1.2, version 1.2, Tomcat and GlassFish. See here for details: http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/07/how-to-add-jslt-taglibs-in-maven-project.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to add it to your pom.xml file.

In the dependencies node you need to add a reference to JSTL.  You will probably need to set its scope to compile.  So it would look something like this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>"whatever version you need"</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is assuming you have the proper references to the maven distribution repository in your pom.xml or settings.xml

Comment: Does this include the `standard.jar` too? I am using GlassFish, should including just the `jstl` dependency work?

Comment: `standard.jar` is for JSTL 1.0. You should absolutely not include it along JSTL 1.1 or newer. If you do so, then EL might stop working because it was originally part of JSTL 1.0 and later moved into JSP 2.0.

Answer (score 33):

The dependencies mentioned above is not enough for me(using Tomcat 5.x as servlet container, which doesn't provide JSTL implementation itself). It just imports the according JSTL interface package into project, and will cause a runtime error in Tomcat.

Here is the dependency part used in my project, hopefully can help others out. The hardest part is the naming of the Apache's JSTL implementation in repository.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>c</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>tld</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>fmt</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>tld</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @dcompiled I don't find official document on this from Maven, but for my guess, tld stands for "Tag Library Descriptor", which itself is XML file.

Comment: for the record, I'm using tomcat 7 and the one given in the accepted answer seems to be enough for me...

Answer (score 3):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>jstl</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2

Comment: jstl group id should be deprecated.
use <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> instead.

Answer (score 3):

From:
   [apache taglib](https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/taglibs/taglibs-standard-1.2.1/README_bin.txt)

```
        <!-- TAGLIB: --> 
          <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
          <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
          <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>  
            <!-- From taglib doc: To use this distribution with your own web applications, add the following JAR
                files to the '/WEB-INF/lib' directory of your application:
                   - taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.1.jar
                   - taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar
                   - taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.1.jar
                   - xalan-2.7.1.jar
                   - serializer-2.7.1.jar
            -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TAGLIB: -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding Apache Tomcat libraries to the Java build path.

See my screenshots, I am using Maven:

Before adding Tomcat libraries:

[image: desc]

After adding Tomcat libraries:

[image: desc]

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- standard.jar --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JSTL --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the last few weeks or so the Maven JSTL dependency has vanished from at least the central repository. This has caused a number of issues around the web.

Oracle has released the separate API and implementation dependencies which is really how they should be broken down. Now, instead of having one javax.servlet.jstl dependency you will use the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And this works.