# How to add JSTL to Maven?

Tags: maven, jstl

I'm working on a JSF 2.0 project using Mojarra, PrimeFaces and Tomcat 6.x.

I need to use c:forEach for some primefaces component like dynamic number of p:tab but i have problem with the c:forEach. All the other tag of JSTL work nice.

I have the following error :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus

I use the following `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`, i tried to replace with `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"` but nothing display with the second.

This is the exact version of lib:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2-FCS</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b03</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

How i can fix it ?

I can give more specific information if needed.

**EDIT:**
I added and tried different scopes (runtime and compile) but nothing change:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The list of repository:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven 1</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>prime-repo</id>
      <name>Prime Technology Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.prime.com.tr</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>JBoss2</id>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>JBoss</id>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
      <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>itextpdf.com</id>
      <name>Maven Repository for iText</name>
      <url>http://maven.itextpdf.com/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>guiceyfruit.release</id>
      <name>GuiceyFruit Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://guiceyfruit.googlecode.com/svn/repo/releases/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

This is the content of $TOMCAT_HOME/lib

> annotations-api.jar   catalina-ha.jar 
>   catalina-tribes.jar   el-impl-2.2.jar 
>   jasper.jar       jsf-api.jar
>   jsp-api.jar   servlet-api.jar
>   tomcat-dbcp.jar
>   tomcat-i18n-fr.jar catalina-ant.jar
>   catalina.jar      el-api-2.2.jar
>   jasper-el.jar     jasper-jdt.jar
>   jsf-impl-2.0.4-b03.jar   ojdbc6.jar
>   tomcat-coyote.jar   tomcat-i18n-es.jar
>   tomcat-i18n-ja.jar

Comment: Tomcat doesn't ship with JSTL out the box. You need to instruct your Maven thing to add JSTL. I improved the title and the tagging to attract the right folks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include JSTL dependency with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276083/include-jstl-dependency-with-maven)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You must include the jstl library in your distribution. This may be provided by the container, although that is not recommended practice. The maven dependency for the current version (as of writing) is here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Although, it's always worth checking the [maven central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl) for updates.

Comment: @HaikalNashuha Usually at the root of your Maven project.

Comment: this may help some, it helped me: [maven setup]( http://www.murraywilliams.com/2011/11/running-jstl-1-2-on-tomcat-7-using-maven/comment-page-1/#comment-71019)

Comment: this thread is old but +1 for the source:

    By default, Tomcat container doesn’t contain any jstl library.

Comment: Actually, the jar does not need to be in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib at all. You should feel free to package it within your web app's war. The dependency is correct though, even though the pre- and post-information is incorrect, so -1 for the bull and well done for finding the correct group id.

Comment: @EngineerDollery EngineerDollery is right, can you please update the answer?

Answer (score 17):

As Balus said, you just need to add JSTL to your pom.xml because Tomcat doesn't include it.  1.2 is the most recent version:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, may be something is missing in my pom or there is some conflicts ?

Comment: Need to include the jstl.jar in the tomcat lib directory and use the scope provided.

Comment: @LaChamelle What server are you using? Have you included standart taglibs as well?

Comment: I get this error too, deploying it to weblogic server and this solution doesn't work. I am also using Maven for the build.

Answer (score 8):

```
<!-- standard.jar --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JSTL --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And then you can use the Java Standart Tags and Functions as follows in your jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="fn" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

This also works alone:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is old, but it's high in the Google results, so I'm adding this.

Newer JSTL version are available (only) under [org.glassfish.web groupId](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.glassfish.web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl). Example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are looking for the [Jakarta EE version](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.glassfish.web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why are these not available in maven repository? https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: They are actually: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl

Answer (score 1):

In recent Tomcat versions use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```