# javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config class not found

Tags: java, jstl

I'm trying use Spring with Hibernate. View uses JSTL. When I open page in browser I see error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationContext(JstlUtils.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:135)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:211)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:212)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This is part of my dependencies from pom.xml which connected with this:

```
<!-- Java EE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Where is a problem?
I am using tomcat version 6.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5168057/81179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in wrong servlet version in web.xml. I've made it 2.5 and all works.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is clear on what the problem is. I know that tomcat by default doesn't include jstl libraries. I see you have added the jstl to your dependency list so it should be part of your web-inf/lib. Make sure it is there.

Comment: I looked this answer:stackoverflow.com/a/5168057/81179, put jstl.jar to lib in tomcat direcotry and it is working now. But why I need put it there if I add dependency?

Comment: @Hleb - I believe the below dependency should take care of this. If not then you need to find what dependency need to be added <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 2):

Add all the jars in `WEB-INF/lib`:

```
jsf-impl.jar
jsf-api.jar
jstl.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-chain.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
```

add then add it to the build path.
It Works!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not put "provided", you force Maven to bring that dependency. Even so, your server should provide that library