# JSF missing "javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config" on a xhtml file

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I am working on panelgroup select menu that would only be visible if the first select Menu wasn't set as a "P" or as a "N". I found an example but before i can try it, I got an error stating

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp
/jstl/core/Config
```

Which is strange because I am sure i am using jsf 2.2 . the only jar file i have my project library is:

```
javax.faces-2.2.5.jar
```

Below is the section of new code i wrote based on a example I found.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" >


<h:body>
<h:form>    
<b>Blue tooth test: </b>  
     <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dliStickerValue}">
     <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass" />
     <f:selectItem itemValue="N" itemLabel="N:A" />
     <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
     <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
     <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
     <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
     <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDliSticker" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="perfbyDliSticker">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.stickerFreq}"
                 rendered="#{!qcFormBean.dliStickerValue eq 'P' or !qcFormBean.dliStickerValue eq 'N'}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="O" itemLabel="Often" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="Seldom" />                
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Is there something i am doing wrong or is the way i am trying to render this not JSF-ish or am i missing more files because I added these files before

jsf-api.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jsf-impl.jar

but then i got a tomcat error in eclipse saying that the file is now a jsp file instead of a jsf file and needs to be added to the web.xml. So there must be some other way about this.

------Update------

Made changes to my code here is the update:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dliStickerValue}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not applicable" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
<f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDliSticker" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="perfbyDliSticker">
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.performedByRoleID}"
                 rendered="#{!qcFormBean.dliStickerValue eq  'P'}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Always" />                
<f:selectItem itemValue="O" itemLabel="Often" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="Seldom" />                
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

--update 2_-----
adding my web.xml to see if it helps.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                                               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
     version="3.0">
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (default). See JSF Specification section 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
 <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>welcome.jsf</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

Comment: it seems the name of jar file wrong `javax.faces-2.2.5.jar` rename it to `javax.faces.jar`

Comment: I renamed the Jar but the error is still there.

Comment: ok try to import and add the jar file to project classpath `/WEB-INF/lib` ?

Comment: its been added on my there already, All i did was change the name of it on the /WEB-INF/lib path. I think i could have the render syntax for the panelgroup incorrect or something.

Comment: The value in the second `selectOneMenu` has a compilation syntax error `#{qcFormBean.}` you need to determine which value in `qcFormBean` managed bean take it after the render success?

Comment: Sorry about that I forgot to add that here. I edited it back in on the question but yes the value is there. Should i use rich Faces or something for this ajax or no?

Comment: you get this error only with ajax or with all your jsf xhtml?

Comment: This error is sadly with it all the ajax and the panelgroup remove that option and it becomes normal. Not sure why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268095/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-core-config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells that the class `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config` is missing. This class is part of JSTL and is not provided by default on Tomcat.

You have to make sure the `jstl-1.2.jar` is present in your `/WEB-INF/lib` (together with the JSF api and impl jars).

**See also:**

- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268095/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-core-config)
- [javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871956/javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-core-config-class-not-found)
- [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113628/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-core-config)

Comment: I added that and now i get the same errors as before and it doesn't even show it as a jsf file:

WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /QcFormDean.jsp.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.

Comment: Maybe you can add your `web.xml` to the question.

Comment: The new problem is unrelated. Open a new question. The current problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

a good structured xhtml could be something like this(`<h:head>...</head>` is important for jsf ajax):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      >
<h:head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Test</title>    
</h:head>
<body>
<f:view> 
<h:outputText value="hello"></h:outputText>
.....
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

if you still have that error, try the following:

create a new Dynamic web Project in eclipse (Kepler EE):

1) menu item file -> new -> Dynamic web Project

2) then enter name for your Project

3) Target runtime (your tomcat server)

4) Modul Version 3.0

5) Configuration: Java Server Faces 2.2 Project

6) next-> next->, then select the checkbox "generate web.xml ..."

7) **next -> JSF Implementation Library (Type: user Library): at the right side you see an icon for download(click it, and wait, you will get Mojarra 2.2 ...), select and install it, finish!**

after that copy my above xhtml and test it in your Pages **(don't forget to add your Faces Servlet pattern in the URL as in your web.xml)**

Comment: Sadly it does have a head, i just didn't think it was important to show it here as it was simple like what you showed.

Comment: @GilbertV:  create a new Projct as i showed above, eclipse will add the libraries correctly!

Comment: But if i deleted the panel group information and the rendereing information the page shows up fine which leads me to think that the part of the code i am using is wrong or incorrect.

Comment: I don't know wasn't me, I ended up doing what you said and just made a new dynamic web project in eclipse to get rid of that error.