# Despite JSTL dependency NoClassDefFoundError still appears

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I've added JSTL dependency in my `pom.xml` file, I can see it in `lib` folder and despite that I'm still getting *500 error* with exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: show us your jsp page. You need to include it in your jsp page also.

Answer (score 0):

Add JSTL Maven Dependency :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Added. Still the same exception and 500 error appears.

Comment: mvn clean didn't helped, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at this answer :

[javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871956/javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-core-config-class-not-found)

The last answer says that it's probably an issue with the servlet version :

> The problem was in wrong servlet version in web.xml. I've made it 2.5
>   and all works.

You can also see dependency relations here :

[The ultimate Java version table (J2EE, Java EE, Servlet, JSP, JSTL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013879/the-ultimate-java-version-table-j2ee-java-ee-servlet-jsp-jstl)