# Why is JSTL causing problems with IntelliJ 14 Ultimate, Tomcat 7, Spring 4.2.1, OSX El Capitan?

Tags: spring, jsp, maven, intellij-idea, jstl

I’ve been wrestling for several days. I have a simple tutorial project and, whenever I added the following directive to my my simple JSP, the page fails to load:

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

**The error from Tomcat**

```
Oct 12, 2015 3:23:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [offers] in context with path [] threw exception [The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or thejar files deployed with this application
```

My files:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>andy</groupId>
<artifactId>pizza</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/java
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"version="3.1">
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <description>Spring Database</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/spring</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      Hello sir!
  </body>
</html>
```

**Project structure in IntelliJ**

[image]

**The page that gets delivered:**

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: change your group id in pom.xml like this <groupId>jstl</groupId> and try to run.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly that didn't seem to make any difference to the outcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148180/how-to-add-jstl-to-maven see this.it may help.

Comment: i have edited my answer.Try other one too.

Comment: Thanks again, but same outcome.

Comment: Did you solved this ?
I'm having the exact same problem on intellij 15

Comment: Yes, an apologies for not sharing my answer! I'll enter the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

which did the trick.