# Spring boot 2.2 activemq jetty conflict

Tags: java, spring-boot, upgrade, embedded-jetty

I am trying to upgrade Spring boot to the version 2.2 together with jetty starter.
I get these errors due to jetty version conflict
The following method did not exist:

```
'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.NativeWebSocketConfiguration org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.NativeWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.initialize(org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler)'
```

The method's class, org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.NativeWebSocketServletContainerInitializer, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/some-dir/target/p3.0.166-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-all-9.4.19.v20190610-uber.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/server/NativeWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.class
jar:file:/some-dir/target/p3.0.166-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/websocket-server-9.4.20.v20190813.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/server/NativeWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.class
```

I have activemq dependency which brings in it's own jetty-all versioned 9.4.19 dependency which is in conflict with spring-boot 2.2 jetty (9.4.20)

[image]

And part of my pom.xml is:

```
       <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <!--
        Jsp-api isn't standard in spring boot
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- artefacts enable JSP running in spring-boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Used to be a single artifact.
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        Newer versions splits the interface and implementation.
        This suggests to use a Glassfish implementation.
        https://www.andygibson.net/blog/quickbyte/jstl-missing-from-maven-repositories/
        The one we used had an Apache implementation, so going with that.
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/24444342
        -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
        <version>${taglibs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${taglibs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
            <!-- Unit test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- html compressing is used by hrmanager in the JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.htmlcompressor</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlcompressor</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ApacheMQ HTTP jarfile set -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?

Comment: I cannot even start spring boot, so there is no full stack trace. But the reason is obvious. activemq-http is using another version of jetty that goes in conflict with default new spring boot 2.2 embedded jetty.

Comment: Can you post your pom?

Comment: I did, I tried excluding jetty-all. It works but I just don't like this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ is wrong here.

`jetty-all` is not meant to be used as a dependency in a project.

See https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html

It only exists as a command line tool for the documentation to educate folks about basic featureset of Jetty.

It does not, and cannot, contain all of Jetty.

A single artifact with *everything* that Jetty produces is impossible.

As @Shilan pointed out, excluding `jetty-all` is the correct solution.

The use of the other appropriate dependencies (by `spring-boot-starter-jetty` it seems) will already pull in the correct Jetty transitive dependencies that you need.

You can use `$ mvn dependency:tree` from the command line to see this (before and after excluding `jetty-all`)

You might want to run one of the duplicate class finder maven plugins to see what other duplicate classes you have going on and correct for those as well.

- https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin
- https://github.com/basepom/duplicate-finder-maven-plugin

Comment: it is not my fault, it comes along with activemq-http dependency. But then I will just exclude it from activemq jar. Hoping it works like it should.

Comment: I know, that's why I filed an issue about it - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-7364

Comment: so just to have it here documented, this is how I excluded the jetty-all
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-http</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
        </dependency>